# Class-based context manager vs generator-based one

Tags: python

There's an `Indenter()` class we could use to have text indentations levels like this:

```
    hi!
        hello
            bonjour
```

The class-based implementation of the context manager is:

```
class Indenter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.level += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.level -= 1

    def print(self, text):
        print('    ' * self.level + text)


with Indenter() as indent:
    indent.print('hi')
    with indent:
        indent.print('hello!')
        with indent:
            indent.print('bonjour')
```

I wonder if it is possible to implement the same solution in the generator-based context manager? The solutions I tried did not work, probably because I just did not grasp the idea of context managers...

UPDATE:
Here's my approach with printing function onboard, so the context yields this function. It is better, but still works only with single indentation:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def indenter():
    level = 0
    def prints(text):
        print('____' * level + text)
    try:
        level += 1
        yield prints
    finally:
        level -= 1

with indenter() as ind:
    ind('aaaa')
    with ind:
        ind('bbbbb')

____aaaa
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError     Traceback (most recent call last)
     29 with indenter() as ind:
     30     ind('aaaa')
---> 31     with ind:
     32         ind('bbbbb')

AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: You forgot about printing.

Comment: Thanks! Updated solution with printing. But still does not work as expected: prints only one level of indentation.

Comment: I re-added the import. Please always include imports with your code. Having to write them by hand or worse, search the Internet to find out where some name lives, takes time that would be better spend actually helping you.

Comment: I wrote the exact same code as above (save some names) and I didn't know what to do next. You are free to accept your own answer but to be honest I do not think that is what you were looking for when you asked the question. At this point I believe a proper solution (if possible at all) would be too complicated to be of any practical use, but it is still an interesting exercise.

Comment: Actually I found that my solution is not quite right, because unlike in original class sample, indentation here does not depend on context __enter__, but on level value I pass manually... :( And yes, I consider this as exercise. I would like to see your solution too, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this. It can be used in a similar way as your class version (but not exactly the same).

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

def indenter():
    level = 0

    def prints(text):
        print('____' * level + text)

    @contextmanager
    def ind():
        nonlocal level
        try:
            level += 1
            yield prints
        finally:
            level -= 1
    return ind


ind = indenter()
with ind() as prints:
    prints('aaa')
    with ind() as prints:
        prints('bbb')
        with ind() as prints:
            prints('ccc')
```

Output:

```
____aaa
________bbb
____________ccc
```