# Supporting with in Your own Objects - Class-based context manager vs generator-based one

Tags: python, python-decorators, with-statement, contextmanager

There's an Indenter() class we could use to have text indentations levels like this:

```
hi!
   hello
      bonjour
hey
```

The class-based implementation of the context manager is:

```
class Indenter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.level += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.level -= 1

    def print(self, text):
        print('    ' * self.level + text)


with Indenter() as indent:
    indent.print('hi')
    with indent:
        indent.print('hello!')
        with indent:
            indent.print('bonjour')
```

I tried to implement the same solution in the generator-based context manager? The solutions I tried did not work.
Same problem was asked earlier [Class-based context manager vs generator-based one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611094/class-based-context-manager-vs-generator-based-one) here but the answer provided is not correct.

So, I thought to ask this question again to get a proper solution.As solution for this problem would help  novice python programmers like me understand basic concepts more clearly.

Comment: You have a working solution, why do you need a generator based one?

Comment: Its for the learning purpose, how generator based would work, as I am not able to make it work. I wanted to know is there a limitation/use-case dependence that we can only create class based solution for this problem and not a generator one.

Comment: Your solution creates a context manager and re-uses the same context manager multiple times, modifying it's internal state with each `with`. This is not easily replicated with a generator based context manager as they do not expose the same state. A class based context manager is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Though this one isn't what you have asked for, it may help. Another one based on decorators, I have used the same message here, but can easily be adapted as well:

```py
def indenter(func):
    def wraps(*args, **kwargs):
        wraps.level += 2
        print("#"*wraps.level, func(*args, **kwargs))
    wraps.level = 0
    return wraps

@indenter
def hi(msg):
    return msg

# Sample Usage
hi("hi")    # ## hi
hi("there") # #### there
hi("holla") # ###### holla
```